# Plot of Number of Oscillations of a Pendulum

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I have been studying the oscillations of a ball attached to a string which is released from some initial angle $\theta$.  The number of complete oscillations over a certain time interval $\Delta t$ is plotted on the $y$-axis of the below plot and I plot

$\frac{l}{(\Delta t)^2 g},$

on the $x$-axis, where $l$ is the length of the string and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

One sees that a curve appears in the data plotted this way.  Is the shape of this curve intuitive?   Can it be explained by the theory of small oscillations of a pendulum, which states that the time period of one oscillation is

$T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}?$

[image]

Comment: About your last question surely YES, because number of oscillations follows $\ell^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected number of oscillations in a period $\Delta t$ is $N = \Delta t / T$.  In terms of your quantity $x = l/g (\Delta t)^2$, you have $\Delta t = \sqrt{l/gx}$.  If you combine these two equations algebraically, you'll have an expected formula for $N$ in terms of $x$, and you can see whether your data matches it.

(As was alluded to in the comments, it certainly seems plausible that it does.  Also, you might consider trying to plot your data on log-log axes;  if your data does conform with the physics expectations then it will look like a straight line on such axes, with a particular slope.)